# How to run python unit test for Google Cloud Functions using Cloud Builds?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-build, google-source-repositories

I am trying to build a CI/CD pipeline for my google cloud functions.
What i have right know is, i have local developement environment with gcloud and git. 
i write my code in local environment and have cloudbuilds.yaml file. 
After writing the code i push it to Google Source Repository where i have Build Trigger. 
It  builds the function and deploy it.

Now i would like to have some test files with it too.That means whenever i push it to source Repository it should also run the tests and build my main.py file and then deploy it.
The cloudbuild.yaml file i have is

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - functions 
  - deploy
  - FunctionName
  - --runtime=python37
  - --source=.
  - --entry-point=function
  - --trigger-topic=topic_name
  - --region=europe-west3
```

Comment: You want to add unit test before the deployment, isn't it? If the test failed, the deployment is not performed, right?

Comment: Yes,exactly! @guilaume

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a step in you Cloud Build. I don't know how your run your test, but here an example for running your script in a python3.7 context

```
- name: 'python:3.7'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
       run the python script that you want
       pip install and others.
```

**Update**

Add this step before your deployment function. If the step fail (exit code different than 0), the cloud build process stopped and the deployment is not performed.

**Update 2**

The concept of Cloud Build is quite simple. You load a container (represented in the `name`). In the container, only the volume `/workspace` is attached and kept from one step to the next one.

This concept is very important. If you set environment variable or other in one step, the step after will loose this context. Only the file of `/workspace` are kept. The next step is call only if the current one finish correctly (exit code = 0).

When a container is loaded, a command is trigger. If you use [cloud builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders), a default entry point is called by default (for example, the gcloud Cloud Builder launch automatically the gcloud command). Then you only have to add the args array to submit to this entry point. Example

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - functions 
  - list
```

This command represent the `gcloud functions list` with `gcloud` as entrypoint and `functions` and  `list` as args.

If your container don't have entrypoint (like python container) or if you want to override your entrypoint, you can specify it with `entrypoint` key word. In my first code example, few linux concept are required. The entrypoint is bash. the arg is `-c` for executing a command. The pipe `|` if for allowing a multi command (multi line) command entry.

If you have only one python command to launch, you can do like this:

```
- name: 'python:3.7'
  entrypoint: 'python3'
  args:
    - 'test_main.py'
    - '.'
```

But, the steps that you wrote won't work. Why? go back to the beginning of my explanation: only the file of the `/workspace` are kept. If you perform a `pip3 install` the files aren't written in the `/workspace` directory, but elsewhere in the system. When you switch of step, you loose this system context.

That's why, a multi-line command is useful

```
- name: 'python:3.7'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
       pip3 install -r requirements.txt
       python3 test_main.py .
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I am using pytest, there are test_cloudfunction.py in the test folder..

Comment: i need to add this step after the step that i have in my question?

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if it's clear enough or not

Comment: i am using pytest for the testing. and i just use pytest to test the functions. do i need to put just 'pytest' after 'c' argument? i am totally new to CI/CD and if possible can you please also provide me some tutorial to get starting and to have a good understanding of this? Thanks!

Comment: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2020/3/5/ab46d3b387e6ad38cf5f03a51c595c6a-full.png

Comment: our build failed to run: failed unmarshalling build config cloudbuild.yaml: unknown field "entry-point" in google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.BuildStep

Comment: I provided a much details behavior of Cloud Build. Do you need more? if so, ask me what!

Comment: Thanks a lot @guillaume. Perfectly explained and worked fine. I have another question related to CI/CD but its a bit off topic. I would make another post for it. Thanks a lot for your help....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209072/discussion-between-hsn-and-guillaume-blaquiere).